# Can you get both skulltula in one runthrough?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

If there's a skulltula for 1,000 KOs, and one for 1200 KO's with < 4 hearts of damage, and I KO 1200 guys with 0 damage taken my first time through the map, will I get both skulltulas? Or does getting the easier one prevent me from also getting the harder one in that runthrough?

Comment: You should be able to get both.

Comment: If they are both for the same character (or any character), I would think so.

Comment: If anyone can find proof that you can, I'll change the checkmark to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished a map (Link's rank 3 fire rod) in which the skulltula requirements were "1000 kills" and "1200 kills without taking 4 hearts of damage before finishing the first mission".

I had 1300 kills before I took the strategic keeps, and I only took 1200 damage the entire map. I got one skulltula when I hit 1000 kills, but the second one did not appear when I got 1200 kills. Either I misunderstood what it meant by "the first mission" (I did have to take out a few bombchus at the start of the map, but there's no way it's possible to kill 1200 enemies before they go off), or it's **not** possible.